# How to show JSON data in HTML

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js

I want to show the following JSON in an Angular page : 
`{"_id":"58b11","name":"Somename","city":"Paris","number":456789123,"__v":0}`

I get this data by clicking on a link in an Angular page:

```
<td ng-click="getData(user._id)"> 
     {{user.name}}  
</td>
```

I am able to get the data from the db and show in the angular page in proper HTML. Now when I click on the link, i get the desired data in JSON on the page `http://localhost:8080/api/students/58b11`. I want to be able to use Angular `{{}}` to show the data in proper HTML format.

Angular :

```
//Created Student factory like this: 
app.factory('Student', function($resource) {
  var data = $resource('/api/students/:id', { id: '@_id' }, {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    }
  });
  return data;
});

//controller: 
app.controller("dummy2", function($scope, $http, Student, $window){

$scope.getData = function(userID){
     $window.location.assign("/api/students/"+userID);
    }
)};
```

NodeJs:

```
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't see how this is related to the other question. This routing is in Ang and the other link if for a normal HTML page.

Comment: why u need redirection ` $window.location.assign("/api/students/"+userID);`

Comment: Cause I want to show the data of only that one user. How else can I achieve this? Please help

Comment: Read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource